# Xcode - iOS app - refactored and now have bizarre, cascading directory structure

Tags: ios, xcode

This is an odd one.

I recently did some refactoring and one of my images was failing to load. I did a search on the filesystem only to find Xcode has now generated the following cascading directory structure:

```
./myIcon.png
./MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
./MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/myIcon.png
```

I'm going to have to go back through my git logs to track down exactly when and how this happened. Is there a quicker/better way of fixing this?

And bonus points for any idea why it happened!

Comment: up voted because I feel your pain...

Comment: no idea why it happened but for anyone else who faces this - I simply moved the subdirectory out of the way. all was well so I just deleted it.